# Can't get Dell warranty info using Python requests and lxml. But browser can

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

```
import requests
from lxml import html

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/18lm9h2/warranty'
    payload = {'ref': 'captchasuccess'}
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36'}
    page = c.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    title = tree.xpath('//*[@id="pd-support-banner"]/div/div/div/div/h1/span/text()')
    warranty = tree.xpath('//*[@id="printdivid"]/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()')
    print(title)
    print(warranty)
```

Dear Python community,

I am trying to get the warranty info of my dell item using python. When I paste the following url: 'http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/18lm9h2/warranty?ref=captchasuccess' on the browser I can get warranty info without issues. However when I use the above code the get the warranty info it gives me an empty list. I know that the code above is correct because it successfully gives me the title of my item. However it does not give me the warranty info. Do you guys have any suggestion? I consider myself a newbie in Python and would greatly appreciate for the explanation of why it does not work.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

change this line:

```
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

to this:

```
print(page.content)
```

and look at the html.

The warranty info is locked behind a CAPTCHA verification check.

To get the warranty info, you'd have to write a program that can detect/solve/submit CAPTCHAs.

Comment: But on the browser it never asks to enter any captcha, it automatically gives the warranty info. Is there a way in python to manage these types of captchas?

Comment: @sir.Suhrab: No, the whole point of the system is to prevent you from doing what you're currently trying to do. Google's CAPTCHA is shown only to users that it thinks are bots. If you've solved one recently in your web browser, you probably won't be shown one.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks a lot!